# How to open a web page with selenium where the browser will have this setting --disable-web-security --user-data-dir --disable-web-security

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, firefox

How can I open a web page on Firefox or Chrome with selenium on python, where the browser will have this setting '--disable-web-security --user-data-dir --disable-web-security'. Normally I can make a shortcut and add this line but then I cant run my selenium script on that. Is there a line of code that I can write to start the browser with those settings ? Or can I add this setting to the base version of the browser that selenium is accessing ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ChromeDriver, you can use `ChromeOptions()` to achieve this. Here's a sample:

```
    var options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
    options.AddArguments("--disable-web-security");
    options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

You can find more documentation & options on ChromeOptions here: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities